# Deleting data in table without Rollback in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have deleted data in a table and didnot rollback. Will the data in that table gets deleted permanently in oracle sql developer?

Answer (score 0):

Will those rows be deleted permanently?

It depends.

- if you didn't rollback, but you didn't commit either, then rows will be deleted within your own session, but any other user will still see all those rows
- check SQL Developer's preferences (Database > Advanced) and see whether the **Autocommit** checkbox is turned on - if so, then although you didn't explicitly commit, tool did that for you. In my opinion, autocommit is generally a bad idea
- even if you did commit, but there's the **flashback** option enabled in your database, then you can restore those rows
- certainly, you should perform regular backup and be able to restore data (that won't save you from losing rows that were inserted/updated between two backups, though)

Basically, there are various options that could & should help you restore deleted rows.

Answer (score -2):

You can recover deleted table records in SQL server by

Step 1: Create a Database. ...
Step 2: Insert Data into Table. ...
Step 3: Delete Rows from Table. ...
Step 4: Get Information about Deleted Rows. ...
Step 5: Get Log Sequence Number of the LOP_BEGIN_XACT Log Record. ...
Step 6: Recover Deleted Records in SQL Server.

Comment: you gave an answer "in SQL server".  The OP did not tag SQL Server (the product from Microsoft).  He did tag 'oracle' and 'oracle-sql developer (products from Oracle)  SQL Server != oracle.